# PerformanceCounterCategory crashing the CLR

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, performancecounter

I have an unmanaged application that uses a managed library. One of the calls the managed component makes is to the `PerformanceCounterCategory` class. It looks like every time any methods are accessed (for example, `PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists(String)`), the CLR crashes pretty hard - exceptions are not catchable, and even the debugger detaches without any errors. I get the following message in the Event Viewer:

> "The description for Event ID 0 from
>   source .NET Runtime cannot be found.
>   Either the component that raises this
>   event is not installed on your local
>   computer or the installation is
>   corrupted. You can install or repair
>   the component on the local computer."
>
> "CorperfmonExt!CollectCtrs caught
>   exception c00000fd"

I've looked at some of the possible solutions (most suggest a corrupt registry is to blame), but none work. If I make the same call in a simple .net 4 application, everything works fine, so I'm fairly certain the system settings are intact. This same code worked just fine before .net 4.

Any insight is appreciated.

Edit: I should add that the unmanaged application is running as a service.

Comment: For what it's worth, 0xc00000fd is STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW (ntstatus.h).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the issue was related to VCL:

http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.interop/browse_thread/thread/f764f9342057d78f/8bc221247a3fd79d

Following the steps described by the author has fixed the problem